# Firefox plugin that can modify incoming data before the page processes it?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, firefox-addon

Say a webpage loads an external javascript at load, is there any such FireFox plugin that I could use to modify the javascript before the page actually processes it?
(not just specifically javascript)

Thanks in advance.
(also I'm pretty sure Tamper Data plugin only changes header data and not actual content being received)

Comment: I don't think there's one out there now. If you do create one, do let the guys here know. :P

Comment: Wouldn't this allow some clever person to change credit card forms to submit somewhere it shouldn't? Disguised as another plugin...

Comment: Why don't you just download the Firefox source code and modify it as per your requirements.

Comment: @Tor Valamo: Yes, but that clever person could hide that in any popular kind of plugin. It's not a reason not to make this one.

Comment: a combination of noscript & grasemonkey may do. the first block all the scripts, the second to read all the scripts and eval the wanted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Tamper Data will modify POST parameters (and GET really since you can modify the URL).
2. You can also combine FoxyProxy (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2464) with any number of free interactive proxies (Fiddler, Paros, Burp, Charles)
3. Finally you can choose to not use a proxy and write up a greasemonkey script.

I think you'll likely have the most luck with the FoxyProxy + proxy approach. Unfortunately it's not a single addon.

Answer (score 6):

For everyone that has never used tamperdata:  Tamper data is for OUTGOING requests.  Tamper Data can modify the ENTIRE request, except the URL which requires you to replay the request.

Using GreaseMonkey  you can make stand-alone custom plugins that can modify any element of the page before it loads.

[Here](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/toc) is THE GUIDE you want which explains GreaseMonkey.

[Here](http://userscripts.org/) are a massive number of GreaseMonkey "UserScripts".  This site contains many examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: I know it can edit elements but it can't edit page resources, images, etc (or can it?)

Comment: Probably not the images themselves,  but you have full control over the html,  so you could change the img links.   If you want to modify binaries then you should go with a proxy.

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately both userscripts.org and diveintogreasemonkey.org no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

The minimalistic browser-agnostic approach would be to write your own bookmarklet. For example I have found the Show Hiddens bookmarklet to be extremely useful for debugging form submissions. While extremely simple the bookmarklet does things which Tamper Data cannot.
I have found it here: 
http://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html

Also the Forms tab in the Web Developer toolbar has some useful options.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to change a downloadable resource, use Opera, set it's cache to never expire, and modify the files cached. That's how I did it a year or two ago, successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I believe GreaseMonkey can modify the data in the page, though I'm not sure if it's executed before or after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Check out TamperMonkey for Chrome: http://tampermonkey.net/

Or if you want to do it manually, in Chrome, it's really simple.

In Chrome, browse to: chrome://extensions. Then drag your .js file into that page.

Chrome will automatically create a manifest.json file in the Chrome AppData folder.
You can change the manifest.json file to filter the websites you want to use your script on.